# Div's inside of button element not showing up in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a little mobile nav button to reveal the navigation on small screens. The kids are calling it "hamburger" these days. It's been working great for me, but just noticed it is not showing up in firefox. It should be a "button" since it triggers some javaScript. I figured, if I made the button display: block; I could put divs within. Is this not the case?

HTML

```
<button class="mobile-nav-button">

  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>

</button> <!-- mobile-nav-button -->
```

CSS

```
.mobile-nav-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0; outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
}

  .bar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 22%;
    margin-bottom: 17%;
    background-color: #f06;
  }

  .bar:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: There is not enough relevant code here for us to help you.  Can you provide enough code (HTML and CSS [rather than SASS] will enable the most people to help you) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I assure you that all of the relevant code is present. I have re-written the syntax just to be clear.

Comment: As for the person who edited the tags, this question has nothing to do with SASS syntax. It does however use html css and 1 css3 selectors.

Comment: Validate your document.  *Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)*

Comment: Add that as an answer and I'll check it off - I figured that might be the issue. Note to self, validate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using div elements try replacing them with span. The button element is an inline type and the div element is block type, because of that some browsers will not interpret this kind of structure correctly.

> **EDIT:**

try this:

```
.mobile-nav-button {
  position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  border: 0; outline: 0;
 /* background: transparent;*/
  width: $m-button-size;
  height: $m-button-size;
  .bar {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 2.7em;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    background: #f06;
    &:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
  }
}
```

> **EDIT2:**

Ok my last solution is to use div or span instead of a button and style it to look like a native button. Also take a look at what cimmanon commented

@cimmanon said:

> Validate your document. Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: You can see that in place here: http://codepen.io/nouveau/pen/vxIdl - unfortunately, it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: that is not a problem with the span elements but with the rendering of styles: if you replace height width 50px and margin with 1px you can view the elements.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: That does work, but the purpose of the percentages was so that it can be changed at any time with 1 number from the variable $m-button-size.

Comment: Ok my last solution is to use div or span instead of a button and style it to look like a native button

Comment: update your answer an combine it with cimmanon's answer, "Validate your document. Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)" and I'll accept it. It's a bummer that I can't use a button, but that is the breaks.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear for future readers, the question was: "I figured, if I made the button display: block; I could put divs within. Is this not the case?" - and the answer is: "No." This is not valid, and while -webkit- seems to let it go, and while semantically and functionally - it *should* be a button... It is just not valid to put divs, inline-block or otherwise, in a <button> element.

Answer (score 0):

Adding content in each `div` worked in this example: http://jsbin.com/eviyah/1/edit

Even just spaces, like

```
<div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bar">&nbsp;</div>
```

However it is desktop and not mobile tested. Maybe it will help!

Comment: Almost! The .bar doesn't hold it's shape though!